# Is there a way to set spark csv number format?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If I'm using `myDF.write.csv("wherever")`, how can I set the numeric format for stored data? EG, if I do:

```
val t = spark.sql("SELECT cast(1000000000000 as double) as aNum")
t.write.csv("WXYZ")
```

and then review `WXYZ`, I will find I have `1.0E12`. How could I change this for all doubles such that I get `1000000000000.00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've handled this issue is by casting the number to a string

```
val t = spark.sql("SELECT cast(1000000000000 as string) as aNum")
t.write.csv("WXYZ")
t.show()
```

And the output is

```
+-------------+
|         aNum|
+-------------+
|1000000000000|
+-------------+
```

:) I hope this helps!

Comment: Ah, I was hoping to do it for a class of items, rather than for each item.

Comment: what do you mean a "class of terms"? like a column?

Answer (score 0):

if data comes from hive there is a hive udf `printf` u can use:

```
select printf('%.2f', col) from foobar
```

planB:

```
dataset.map( col => s"$col%.2f")
```

take care of planB, there may be extra cost based on your data source

btw, sometimes it is likely just a problem of display in excel, just check the csv with text editor